# What to do when force pushing is denied by remote hub?

Tags: git, gitlab, git-reset, git-amend

Okay, so this is a question after the fact, and I just want to know what I should've done so I can avoid this problem in the future. Yes, I realize force pushing is a dangerous command. Yes, I realize `git reset HEAD --hard` can be a dangerous command too. Please help me avoid this problem that cost me ~4 hours of work today.

So here's what happened:

I had edited about 6 files on my current working branch. 3 of those files I wasn't ready to commit yet, so I staged and wrapped 3 of the files into a commit and pushed them to my remote. This left me with 3 unstaged files on my local that contained the bulk of my work.

Soon after pushing, I realized I made a minor typo in one of the files I had just pushed. So instead of adding another commit for the typo, I tried to amend my last commit and force pushed. I then received this error:

```
remote: GitLab: You are not allowed to force push code to a protected branch on this project.
```

I believe this was a recent global change made by the maintainer of our enterprise GitLab servers.

Now, this is a personal repo I am the maintainer of; hence why I had no qualms to force push. Especially when it was just a tiny change, and no one else's local git history was going to be messed up due to the push.

But now I was left with a predicament. I have this amended commit on my local machine that I would never be able to push to the remote. So I figured I needed to reset so I could just add an additional commit for the typo. So I ran:

```
git reset HEAD~1 --hard
```

And, as I'm sure you've guessed, I lost all the files that I hadn't staged for commit yet. *facepalm*...

What should I have done in this situation? And while I'm pretty sure those files are gone forever, is there any slight hope I could recover those changes?

Comment: When in doubt, commit all unsaved work and clean up later.

Comment: Have you checked settings - repository - protected branches? There is a flag you can enable

Comment: Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5473/how-can-i-undo-git-reset-hard-head1 for how to undo a hard reset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best would have been to stash the uncommited changed files. Something like this:

```sh
git status
# Shows 6 files uncommited changes
git add file1 file2 file3
git commit -m "Update file 1, 2, 3"
git push origin feature-branch-123
git status
# Shows 3 files uncommited changes
# work, work, work, ...
# notice forgot something in file1
git add file1
git commit --amend --no-edit
git push origin feature-branch --force-with-lease
# returns remote: GitLab: You are not allowed to force push code to a protected branch on this project.

# Now the difference:
# before reset, stash changes
git stash push
git status
# no local changes detected
git reset HEAD~1 --hard
# restore stashed changes
git stash apply
git status
# Shows 3 files uncommited changes
```

Stashing also works with untracked files (`-u`) and you can have multiple stashes if you work on different topics in parallel. Read more about [stashing](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Stashing-and-Cleaning).

Other than that, you could also have done a soft or a normal reset. That way you wont loose your local changes. Read more on the [topic](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Reset-Demystified).

If not done, I would recommand to read the [git book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/) and take a look at [dangitgit](https://dangitgit.com/) for some complex troubleshooting, both free.