# How do reset/revert a git reset HEAD~

Tags: git, git-reset

By mistake I did a `git reset HEAD~` in my branch. I see all my changed files on my local. I don't want to change anything. The branch is good as is.

What do I have to do?

Comment: take a look at the reflog (`git reflog`) and then use the right commit id to do another `git reset`.

Comment: `git reset "HEAD@{1}"` https://stackoverflow.com/a/5127681/7976758 (but do not use `--hard` as it removes local changes.) Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-reset%5D+undo

Comment: @phd Why not just making this question a duplicate of the one you linked? It seems similar enough, but maybe there's something I missed?

Comment: @RomainValeri The option `--hard` (all over the the linked Q and As) is a rather dangerous one for an unprepared user. I'd like the OP to report success or comment why he's not satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you haven't done anything else, just do this command `git reset --hard HEAD@{1}`. If you've made other changes, do `git reflog show` to see which commit you want to revert back to. Then do `git reset --hard XXX` and put that commit ID in the XXX part.
2. You then `git push --force` to make sure your remote branch reflects the change.

Comment: Using `--hard` is unnecessary in the presented situation. Suggesting it makes the operation unnecessarily dangerous. See also the comments by @phd above.