# I reset my application with Git, how can I undo it?

Tags: git

I accidentally set my entire Next.js application to zero with the command git reset --hard origin/master.

```
git fetch --all
git reset --hard origin/master
```

How can I reset everything?

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5473/438992

Comment: In the end it'll depend on what you've done locally, whether or not you're using an IDE/etc that tracks local history, etc. E.g., if you were working in a branch and so on.

Comment: [Please post code/errors/etc as formatted text instead of images of formatted text.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)